# Is a set of connected vertexes that do not create a face an ngon?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

Is there a chance for artefacts to appear if a part of the mesh has more than 4 vertexes that do not form a face; e.g. plates stacked on each other where the bottom has no face.

There is a small wedge between the cube and initial mesh:

[image: This description should not be necessary]

[image: This description should not be necessary]

[image: This description should not be necessary]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). That's called non-manifold geometry. What kind of artifacts do you have in mind?

Comment: maybe give a try and show and share the result?

Comment: @moonboots Edited. Is the base of the mesh an ngon or not since the vertexes don't form a face

Comment: An ngon is a **face**, with more than 4 verts.

Comment: @batFINGER Ok. So it's ok to put another cube beneath the selected mesh and merge it to it? Since it's not an ngon it can't be messed up during rendering, right?

Comment: Hello @Sebi :). Have you noticed n-gons being somehow 'messed up' during rendering? They might cause some artifacts with *Subdivision Modifier* or when they're non-planar. But flat n-gons? These are usually fine. Also, such n-gon would be trivial to turn into quads :).

Comment: Since no one has answered, consider updating question with "merge cube below" details. Posted [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) link earlier where it prob wasn't a case, a bit gun shy, but feel this is the case here.

Comment: @Jachym Michal  In this case not (yet) but I don't want to apply the modifier to the entire mesh. If I create a face from the corner vertexes of the bottom rectangle the mesh is closed and the modifier applied. It's not flat as I'd like but beveled. Now, I want to create parallelepiped as a separate mesh and move it close to the bottom vertxes and then apply the modifier in the first mesh save it and merge it to the second?

Comment: @batFINGER Done. Added details + blend